# Existence of a stronger notion of perfect measures

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a measurable space with its $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X}$ and let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real numbers endowed with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

Recall that a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}$ is called *perfect* if for every measurable map $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$ f_*(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu = (\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})_{f_*\mu}, $$
where $(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu$ is the completion of $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X}$ w.r.t. $\mu$, and, $(\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})_{f_*\mu}$ the completion of $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t. the push-forward measure $f_*\mu$ (restricted to $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$), given by $(f_*\mu)(B):=\mu(f^{-1}(B))$, and, $f_*(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu$ the push-forward $\sigma$-algebra given by:
$$ f_*(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu := \{ B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\,|\, f^{-1}(B) \in  (\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu \}. $$
It is known that perfect measures are "well-behaved" w.r.t. *countably separated* measurable spaces. For example, if $\mathcal{Y}$ is a countably separated measurable space and $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ any measurable map then we also have:
$$ f_*(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu = (\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{Y})_{f_*\mu}.$$
The assumption of countably separatedness sometimes seems a bit restrictive in general and I wonder if the following stronger notion of perfect measures was already studied and if so if non-trivial examples exists:

Lets call a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}$ *Stone perfect* if for every measurable map $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Z}$ to a Stone space (= pro-finite set = totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space) $\mathcal{Z}$ endowed with its *Baire* $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{Ba}_\mathcal{Z}$ we have:
$$ f_*(\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{X})_\mu = (\mathcal{Ba}_\mathcal{Z})_{f_*\mu}.$$
Note that the Baire $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the zero sets of all continuous maps $h:\mathcal{Z}\to [0,1]$, and, on Stone spaces it is also generated by the clopen (=closed-and-open) subsets of $\mathcal{Z}$.

One can show that Stone perfect probability measures are countably compact and thus perfect. So the new notion appears to be more restrictive than being a perfect probability measure.

The concrete question is now:
Is the uniform distribution $\nu$ on the unit interval $[0,1]$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra Stone perfect?